# How do I find and replace in file1 with values from file2

Tags: command-line, files, scripts, text-processing

file1

```
O,tested test,12345
OC,test explore,34567
```

file2

```
O,new order
OC,new quote
```

I need an output like below:

```
New order,tested test,12345
New quote,test explore,34567
```

Comment: It depends what your exact requirements are - does the capitalization really need to change (`new quote` --> `New quote`)? Do you care about the final order of entries? If not, a simple `join` command should suffice.

Comment: Can you be sure all lines in file1 *do* have a match in file2 and vice versa?

Comment: what is the logic here? match based on line number or based on the names?

Comment: It is based on names...basically I want first column of file1 to be replaced with values from file 2.

Comment: Basically I want first column of file 1 to be mapped with value from file2

Comment: one more request can this happen real time like when the file 1 has records being added and gets continously replaced?

Answer (score 3):

That's a job for `join`:

```
join -t, -j1 -o 2.2,1.2,1.3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

- `-t` specifies the input and ouput separator
- `-j1` is the join field (in both files the first one)
- `-o ...` the format of the output as desired in the question

Answer (score 3):

This is something `awk` handles very well by reading one file in memory and then replacing the items in the other one:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {$1=a[$1]}1' f2 f1
new order,tested test,12345
new quote,test explore,34567
```

The idea is to store the values from file2 in an array `values[file1]=file2`. Then, when reading the file1 we replace the 1st field with the mapping in the `values[]` array.

Note this can be extended to take into consideration cases when fields are not present in the array or many more things.

Comment: o_O sorry, my mistake

Comment: @A.B. no problem.  In case it was based on number if would need `a[NR]=$2` and then say `$1=a[FNR]`.

Comment: Thanks this worked.Can you let me know how to enhance this to replace it in the file2 instaed of printing it to stdout.

Comment: @Testpriya you can say `awk '...' file2 file1 > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file2`. That is, redirect to a temporary file and then replace the original one.

Comment: Thank you...one more request can this happen real time when the file 1 has records being added  and gets continously replaced?

Comment: @Testpriya that is a very different issue. If that's what you need, please [edit] your question and explain it. It is possible but more complex.